# Can I call an R function while using open FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq?

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing, f#, type-providers

I have some code that runs with no problems without parallelization. However, the same code generates exceptions if I try to run it using `PSeq` instead of `Seq`. The messages I get look a bit random, they are hard to replicate exactly.

Here is the code. When the exception happens the three lines starting with `let tmp2` are highlighted.

```
let frameToRMatrix (df: Frame<'R,string>) =

    let foo k df : float list =
        df
        |> Frame.getCol k
        |> Series.values
        |> List.ofSeq

    let folder acc k = (k, foo k df |> box) :: acc

    let tmp =
        List.fold folder [] (df.ColumnKeys |> List.ofSeq)
        |> namedParams

    let sd = df |> Frame.getCol "Vol0" |> Series.lastValue
    let sd = sd * 1000.0 |> int

    printfn "%s" "I was here"

    let rand = System.Random(sd)
    let rms = rand.Next(500)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep rms

    let tmp2 =
        tmp
        |> R.cbind // This line prints something on the console the first time it is executed

    printfn "%s" "And here too"

    tmp2
```

The code above includes random number generation and calls to `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep`. If I do not include this code, which is not needed under sequential execution, I get a message:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.'
```

and the following on the console:

```
I was here
I was here
[1] 4095
```

So execution never gets to the `And here too` lines.

When I include the random number generator and the call to `sleep` I get different results, which seem to depend on the build options.

Below are four examples, with the build options, error message and what I see on the console. Notice that in all examples there are four instances of `I was here` but only three instances of `And here too`.

```
---------------------------------------
Any CPU with Prefer 32-bit checked 
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: 'External component has thrown an exception.'

I was here
I was here
[1] 4095
And here too
I was here
And here too
I was here
And here too
Warning: stack imbalance in 'lazyLoadDBfetch', 66 then 65
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : unprotect_ptr: pointer not found


    ---------------------------------------
Any CPU with Prefer 32-bit unchecked 
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: 'External component has thrown an exception.'


I was here
I was here
[1] 1.759219e+13
And here too
I was here
And here too
I was here
And here too
Error: cons memory exhausted (limit reached?)
Error: cons memory exhausted (limit reached?)




    ---------------------------------------
x86
System.AccessViolationException" 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'


I was here
I was here
[1] 4095
And here too
I was here
And here too
I was here
And here too

    ---------------------------------------
x64
Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in Unknown Module. Attermpted to read or write protected memory.
$$$ - MachineLearning.signal: Calculating signal for ticker AAPL
$$$ - MachineLearning.signal: Calculating signal for ticker AAPL
I was here
I was here
[1] 1.759219e+13
And here too
I was here
And here too
I was here
And here too
Error in loadNamespace(name) :
  no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience with debugging subtle issues with threading in the R type provider, I think the answer is no - sadly, the R native interop layer is not thread-safe and so you cannot call it from multiple threads in your F# application.

I think that the standard way of running R in parallel is to spawn multiple `R.exe` processes doing the work. I don't think you can easily initialise multiple independent R processes from F#, so your best bet is probably to create multiple .NET processes that each controls one R engine.

Comment: Calling List.map on identical arguments, I created two identical objects, instances of the same class and executed the same method (call it obj.crashable, the one that crashed) for each object. I configured the crashable methods to run sequentially. So parallelization was a a higher level in the call tree. Interestingly the program did not crash but my CPU usage remained at 15%, as it did when I did the same thing but with only one of the two objects.